Json .NET issue trying to access value
Using NewtonSoft Json.Net on Unity3D, I can update/add/remove entries except when using the following.
This is the json:
    string remoteJson = @"{
        player: 'MyName',
        score: 1000,
        lastLogin : '12/20/20154:50:30AM'
    }";

Then it gets passed to this to update m_jsonObject:
public bool SetUserPrefsFromRemote(string remoteUserPrefs)
{
    if (!IsValidJson(remoteUserPrefs)) 
    {
        Debug.LogError("[UserPrefs] Invalid Json from remote");
        return false;
    }
    m_jsonObject.RemoveAll();
    m_jsonObject = JObject.Parse(remoteUserPrefs);
    SaveLocal();
    return true;
}

then calling this method to retrieve the value, it fails at the HERE line.
 public bool TryGetValue<T>(string key, out T value, T defaultValue) 
 {
     value = defaultValue;
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) 
     {
         return false;
     }        
     if (!IsInit) 
     {
         Debug.LogError("[UserPrefs] Attempt to access UserPrefs while not initialized");
         return false;
     }
     if (m_jsonObject == null)
     {
         return false;
     }
     if (m_jsonObject.TryGetValue(key, out JToken jtoken))
     {
         value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jtoken.ToString()); // HERE
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }

Error :
Unity.Plastic.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: M. Path '', line 1, position 1.

When debugging, I can't see anything wrong, "MyName" shows properly. It works just fine when adding the entries one by one with the following :
    public void SetValue(string key, object value) 
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) 
        { 
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Provided key is null or empty while setting value");
        }
        m_jsonObject[key] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        });
        SaveLocal();
    }

EDIT:
The issue is only on the string, after parsing here the JObject:
"{\r\n  \"player\": \"MyName\",\r\n  \"score\": \"1000\",\r\n  \"lastLogin\": \"12/20/20154:50:30AM\"\r\n}"

if I use SetValue then it gets as such:
"{\r\n  \"player\": \"\\\"MyName\\\"\",\r\n  \"score\": \"1000\",\r\n  \"lastLogin\": \"12/20/20154:50:30AM\"\r\n}"

Somehow SetValue adds those extra \\ before and after the string value and DeserializeObject works.

Are you sure you are not maybe passing in \"MyName\" as value? .. the \ is not the only thing being added but is rather an escaped leading and trailing \"

All the code involved in the process is there. I'm just surprised that JObject.Parse does its work but then getting the value fails. I'm thinking I could iterate all the tokens to set them properly but Parse should create a usable JObject

your code does not include how exactly you call SetValue though .. I believe it is receiving the string including the \" so question is where do your parameters come from?

I somewhat suspect that you might be using ToString where you actually would rather use Value<string> to obtain the value

'm_userPrefs.SetValue(key, "MyName");' here's how I call it.  So there the difference that it comes as an object type parameter. Maybe something there.

The issue is that you actually do encode every value as a JSON string!
You use JsonConvert.SerializeObject before assigning your values to the m_jsonObject basically storing nested JSON encoded strings - within a JSON.
If you look closely the issue is not

only on the string, after parsing here the JObject

even the number values are wrong as in JSON format it should e.g. not be
"score": "1000"

but rather
"score": 1000

making it a numeric (int) field rather than an encoded string.
In your specific case what happens is that you call
m_userPrefs.SetValue(key, "MyName");

which in the first JsonConvert.SerializeObject converts MyName to \"MyName\" and stores it this way. And when you then finally serialize the entire object back to a JSON string these \" get further escaped to \\\".
So it should probably rather be
public void SetValue<T>(string key, T value) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) 
    { 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key), "Provided key is null or empty while setting value");
    }

    m_jsonObject[key] = JToken.FromObject(value);
    SaveLocal();
}

And then also the other way round when reading the values you are expecting a nested JSON string and use
value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jtoken.ToString());

It should rather be something like
value = jtoken.ToObject<T>();


Thanks a lot for that, so I tried the suggestion but m_jsonObject[key] = (JToken) value; raises questions since the implicit conversion is from string to JToken but T can be anything from int to custom class type.

@Everts yeah the cast was wrong since T is too generic and there is no direct conversion from just anything to JToken ... I updated this to rather use JToken.ToObject and JToken.FromObject which works for more than just the existing implicit conversions (for instance e.g. also for dictionaries and arrays etc)

Alright, it seems to pass all the tests! Thanks a lot for your help.
